# Connection between Vanguard spacecraft, Vanguard rocket, and Project Vanguard?

Tags: history, terminology, united-states, vanguard

I think I created the [vanguard](/questions/tagged/vanguard) tag for [Why would low pump inlet pressure result in such a spectacular explosion? (Vanguard TV3)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38500/12102) and now I'm not sure of the connection between the Vanguard spacecraft, Vanguard rocket, and Project Vanguard.

Did any of these draw their names from another? Are they closely linked, do they overlap, or are they fairly unrelated except for containing the word "Vanguard" in their names?

Comment: You might have a [Columbia](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/tagging-questions-on-space-shuttle-columbia-and-sts-107) issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Vanguard), they're all related: Project Vanguard launched Vanguard satellites on Vanguard rockets, but only [3 of 11 launches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanguard_(rocket)) succeeded.  The US Naval Research Lab that ran the project [doesn't have much to say](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/accomplishments/rockets/vanguard-project) about it.